# Narrow down type or interface function signature's parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a type that defines a function's signature like so:

```
type TLoggerCallback = ((loggerMessageType: string, loggerErrorLevel: TLoggerLogLevel, object: object) => void)
```

In one class, I'd like to import `TLoggerCallback` and define a new function signature starting from this one, narrowing down the `object` parameter to a specific type of object, thus defining a new (e.g.) `TClassLoggerCallback` defined like so:

```
type TClassLoggerCallback = ((loggerMessageType: string, loggerErrorLevel: TLoggerLogLevel, object: { prop1: string }) => void)
```

Please mind that `object` should stay an object at all times; so I should be able to "override" its definition by defining a more specific object but I shouldn't, e.g., be able to make it a string.

How do I go about "overriding" (in this case by narrowing down) `TLoggerCallback`'s `object` parameter like so?

The idea obviously is to have a generic logger callback type which can be narrowed down for each specific use case, in order to get the advantages of having the parameter more strictly typed (for the usual stuff, such as completion, errors etc...)

If that requires defining `TLoggerCallback` as an interface in the first place, I'm perfectly fine with doing that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep `TLoggerCallback`, but change the `object` field type at will. You can achieve this with the use of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```js
type TLoggerCallback<T extends Record<string,any>> = ((..., object: T) => void)
```

`T extends Record<string,any>` ensures that only objects are passed as type arguments.
You can use it this way

```
type ClassType = { prop1: string }

const test: TLoggerCallback<ClassType> = (..., object: { prop1: string } ) => {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgMgewOZIgJ0UuEBuEA2UAvFAIYB2IUA9NVADwC0jUAggCbsTtQBGEAY1IBXAM7QQCYVHYBLduQDkwKKMgDZAMyoB3ABakV8ZKgzJseQrNEA6AFB3QkWJlMBhUvny9SAgNb0MFAQAB7AEOTsolAASoIIaOz0osBosuRIADQUIAB8ucRQABT4JugAshCioqSoMOAQAFyqqelZUKUo6ACiaGgJFgTNxl1mWLgEmVAIvABWgsDDAJTEBTgI8g5O0G74pNX1ziQA3lBg-WAAjM0paRlQAL4OAgjkKVDhKcOu6B5ePv56Lt9qJDhACiQSmU0JVqrUIGCbq0MlNOqZev0MBN8N9oZhBvgpjN5gJFlBTucEFckXckI8oCsiAVjg8oHYXm8VJ9gAB9Rojdyeby+AK3NoQ4poipVGp1Bo0tqo6EYgbY3GjfHYolzBYK+6M5ms2hQFVoPiCETiKCocjoWQCM6kNCkAC2EHCZusUHICBUFGmOtJ7Ne725PL5Lmhf2FgOBBwaEqho1hsoR8patKVo1NBPVpk1lm1JLJp1ECDdAHlgHp0AAFC56umsg3ko10U3moRiaBlyvVusXGQIKpKFShawqOOghpAA)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I ended up using `type TClassLoggerCallback = TLoggerCallback<ClassType>` to define the type, which is exactly what I needed. I'm trying to apply this to primitive values as well (i.e. "narrowing down" strings to a specific union of strings), but to no avail. Do you happen to know the right syntax to use there? Would that warrant a new question (although I'm pretty sure that's trivial stuff already answered in different forms 2000 times)? I tried `T: string` in place of `T extends Record<string,any>`, but that throws a syntax error. In any case thank you again!

Comment: Well nevermind again, I managed to do it with `T extends string`. Never had to use generics so I guess it's time to read something about it. Thanks!